# Why getMetadata() doesnt work on m4a files in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, metadata, audio-player

I am trying to make a music player using javafx 2.0.

I can get details of .mp3  files but I can't get metadata details of m4a and .wav songs. How can I fix this?

```
ObservableMap<String,Object> meta_data=media.getMetadata();

meta_data.addListener(new MapChangeListener<String,Object>(){

public void onChanged(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> ch) { 

   if(ch.wasAdded()){

        String key=ch.getKey();
        Object value=ch.getValueAdded(); 

           switch(key){

               case "album":
               System.out.println("Albume: "+value.toString());
               break;

               case "artist":  
               System.out.println("Artist: "+value.toString());
               break;

               case "title":
               System.out.println("Title: "+value.toString());
               break;

               case "year":
               System.out.println("Year: "+value.toString());
               break;

               case "genre":
               System.out.println("Genre: "+value.toString());
               break;   

               case "image":
               image.setImage((Image)value);
               break;
          }
      }         
   }
```

});

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: I cant get name of artist , name of album ( details) of .m4a songs! Do you have any idea to get them?!@jmelosegui

Answer (score 0):

Metadata for m4a files aren't supported yet in Java 8, neither for wav files: [Supported Metadata Tags](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMetadataTags)

Comment: Do you know how can i get details of m4a?

Comment: You could use 3rd party libraries.